# unable to connect to Splunk using javascript sdk

Tags: javascript, cypress, splunk

I am currently trying to use javascript splunk sdk with cypress and setting it up. I have followed the tutorial but am getting errors

The error is
`splunkjs.ProxyHttp is not a constructor`

Why is this happening?

```
var splunkjs = require('splunk-sdk');

before(() => {
    var http = new splunkjs.ProxyHttp('/proxy')
    var service = new splunkjs.Service({
        'scheme':'https',
        'host':Cypress.env('SPLUNK_HOST'),
        'port':8089,
        'username':Cypress.env('SPLUNK_USER_NAME'),
        'password':Cypress.env('SPLUNK_PASSWORD')
        });
            cy.log('hi')
            cy.log(service)
        service.login(function(err, success) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            }

            cy.log("Login was successful: " + success);
            service.jobs().fetch(function(err, jobs) {
                var jobList = jobs.list();
                for(var i = 0; i < jobList.length; i++) {
                    cy.log("Job " + i + ": " + jobList[i].sid);
                }
            });
        });
})
```

Comment: what tutorial did you follow? What error(s) are you getting? What version of Splunk? Of Cypress?

Comment: Version of splunk: 1.12.1 and cypress: 11.1.0. Ive been following the tutorial https://dev.splunk.com/enterprise/docs/devtools/javascript/sdk-javascript/gettingstartedsdkjavascript

Comment: The error is in the description

Comment: you listed an error ... but you don't say from where it originated: Cypress? the Javascript console? somewhere else?

Comment: ah apologies, it was from Cypress